# How can I compare this.props.children with nextprops.children

Tags: reactjs

In componentWillReceiveProps I need to compare this.props.children with the children in nextprops. I can iterate over either structure with React.Children.forEach but I haven't found any sanctioned mechanism to index either "opaque" structure.

Comment: Why do you need to compare them in componentWillRecieveProps? Most common case for comparing old and new props that I know of is in shouldComponentUpdate, when you want to increase performance by completely skipping the render part of the lifecycle

Comment: Why does that matter? You haven't answered my question. You haven't said "You should never compare props.children with nextprops.children because...".  I want to change state, perhaps. But it doesn't matter, if I said "fine, I'll do it in shouldComponentUpdate" what would your answer be?

Comment: I tried to get more info so that I might be able to answer your question, hence I posted a comment on your question rather than an answer.

Comment: `this.props.children` is referred to as "opaque" because it can be undefined (0 children), an object (1 child), or an array of objects (2+ children). It's reasonable to access `this.props.children` directly, but without using the [`React.Children`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children) helpers you will need to handle the three legal states yourself.

Answer (score 0):

ComponentWillReceiveProps isn't called after the first render: http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/componentWillReceiveProps-not-triggered-after-mounting.html You need to do what the other comment says, use shouldComponentUpdate.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of that. Still, how can I index children? How can I find the i-th child in props.children or nextprops.children?

Comment: this.props.children will just be an array, you can map it easily.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation provides utilities for dealing with the this.props.children opaque data structure:

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children

You can index this.props.children either with `React.Children.map` or `React.Children.forEach`:

> ```
> object React.Children.map(object children, function fn [, object context])
> ```
>
> Invoke fn on every immediate child contained within children with this
>   set to context. If children is a nested object or array it will be
>   traversed: fn will never be passed the container objects. If children
>   is null or undefined returns null or undefined rather than an empty
>   object.
>
> ```
> React.Children.forEach(object children, function fn [, object context])
> ```
>
> Like React.Children.map() but does not return an object.